# Query search from spring boot to remote elasticsearch service

Tags: rest, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I need to create an API in spring boot that receives a query string and pass that string to remote elasticsearch service. I need get the response in JSON format. Is there a way to do that? or Is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: show what you have done so far and be specific

Comment: I need pass an string query to remote elasticsearch service and I need get the response